# Can I edit a constructor function in javaScript to add properties?

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor

I have this basic constructor function(with two inputs)

`function Person(firstName, lastName) { this.firstName = firstName; this.lastName = lastName; }`

To create an object with the constructor function **Person**, I do

`var person1 = new Person("John", "Doe");`

[the output is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0eG0.png)

if I want to add a new property to the object **person1** (*age*, for example), I do

```
person1.age = 20;
```

[and the output is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7hQF.png)

now, I want to create a new object with the same constructor function... let say **person2**. Because I know his age, I want to add this info to the object too. I do it like this

```
var person2 = new Person("Jennifer", "Unknown", 30);
```

[the output is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfxmo.png)

the output comes without the *age* property, because the constructor function **Person** doesn't know it

To create the object **person2** with those 3 inputs using **Person**, I must redefine **Person** (with those 3 inputs) and recreate **person2**, passing those 3 info's or add the extra info if object already exists ...

My question is:

How to proceed, if I want to add a third object with **Person** (**person3**), by passing 4 inputs (*firstName*, *lastName*, *age*, *nationality*)? I have to redefine **Person** (again) and then create **person3**? ... This seems tedious and not logic work! I confess I'am a newbie in jS!

is it there a way to edit a constructor function without redefining it every time I want to create a new object with extra properties? Can I add new property to a constructor functions without redefining it? And, if I want to edit a constructor function to add a method? for example:

```
status = function(){
  alert(this.firstName + " " + this. lastName + " " + ", a person with" + " " + this. age + " " + "years old" + " " + "was found nearby doing jS stuff!" )}
```

summarizing... my goal is:

I start with [start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZTIQ.png) and want to end with [end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh9bi.png) without redefining **Person**, just editing it.

My question make sense? I appreciate any tip.

Comment: Try to include all possible properties you need the *first* time you write the function, else, yes, you will have to go back and re-write it

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no such thing as "edit" a function, but you can reuse the old implementation to define your new function instead of rewriting it completely.

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName
  this.lastName = lastName
}
Person.prototype.speak = function () {
  console.log('hey!')
}

p1 = new Person('first1', 'last1')

console.log('p1 firstName', p1.firstName)
p1.speak() // hey!

// store old prototype object
oldPrototype = Person.prototype


Person = function (firstName, lastName, age) {
  // call the old constructor to initialize with existing properties
  oldPrototype.constructor.call(this, firstName, lastName)

  // assign new properties
  this.age = age
  // assign a new default property
  this.otherProp = 'new prop'
}

// copy over the old prototype to the new Person
Person.prototype = oldPrototype

p2 = new Person('first2', 'last2', 10)

console.log('p2 firstName', p2.firstName)
console.log('p2 new properties', p2.age, p2.otherProp) // 10 and 'new prop'

p2.speak() // should work! because we already copied the old prototype object over

// it will not affect any of the old Person instances that were initialized before
console.log('p1 age', p1.age) // undefined
console.log('p1 otherProp', p1.otherProp) // undefined
```

While this is possible, don't overuse it!

Because it seems like an anti-pattern to override a `constructor` function.
You should better create a new `constructor function` by extending your `Person` instead.

Read more about [Inheritance in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance)